# laravel 4.2 send email display custom name for the attachment

Tags: php, mysql, email, laravel-4, attachment

I have the following code:

```
$message->to($user->W_EMAIL_ADDRESS, '')
        ->subject($user->W_SUBJECT.$user->W_SITE_ADDRESS)
        ->attach($user->W_PATH_FILE);
```

[image: The email I received shows the value in files.filename]

Is it possible to display the value I put in the files.name?

Comment: try this `$message->attach($pathToFile, array('as' => $display, 'mime' => $mime));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
$message->attach('path_to_pdf_file', array(
    'as' => 'name to display.pdf', 
    'mime' => 'application/pdf'));
```